# How to concatenate date(mm/dd/yyyy) with time (hh:mm:ss) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells: A1 and B1

- A1 has data in format of `mm/dd/yyyy`
- B1 has data in format of `hh:mm:ss`

When I concatenate the two cells A1 and B1 using VBA, the output contains has the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`. Why are the seconds not displaying? How can I fix this?

Note :

a) After concatenation the output is copied to A1.

b) I tried changing the format of date to `dd/mm/yyyy`, in this case its working fine .

Comment: When i do double click on output cell , seconds are appearing  but normally its not appearing.

Comment: Note: I am using format function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are doing exactly without seeing your code, but I think you are specifying the format of the value you are writing to cell A1: using the VBA `Format` function you are converting the date-time into a string.

However, to change the way the date is *displayed* in a cell, you need to change the format *of that cell itself* (not the format of the *value* written to it). Otherwise Excel will likely interpret the value in the cell and snap it back to the specified number format for that cell.

You can change the cell's format in the Excel 2010 window like this: Home > Number > Custom > Type: `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss`

Or, using VBA:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"
```

Comment: Thank you very much .Got it ..Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss" worked .

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the format of C1 to 
`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy is working .. but I need in mm/dd/yyyy ..In case of mm/dd/yyyy , its not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working?
`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` also works

Comment: Output is coming as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm                               seconds are not displayed ..

Comment: Thanks @sam092 ..as mentioned below it was issue with number format .

Comment: okay:) kinda weird. coz that line is doing the exact same thing