# Excel macro vba script

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to format a column in excel sheet where regular format datetime to date option is not working as I exported data in excel from clear quest. I need date column in mm/dd/yyyy format bis there a VB script that can do this.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19801598/119775

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DateFormat()
     Range("C2:C64").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: If it's for only one column C range C2:C64 how will the code be ?

Comment: @user803860 - Change "Columns("G:G").Select" to "Range("C2:C64").Select"

Comment: Sub DateFormat() ' 'Change G:G to the column(s) you would like to change ' Columns("C2:C64").Select Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" Range("C2").Select End Sub

Comment: @user803860 - you have to change "Columns" to "Range".......or, just use the new code after I did the edit to my answer.

Comment: @user803860 - did this do what you needed?  if so, please mark as answered.  if not, please let me know what you are seeing.  thanks :)

Comment: That didn't work seems like when you export from clear quest it doesn't let u format

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post: [Excel VBA date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801598/excel-vba-date-formats)

```
Function CellContentCanBeInterpretedAsADate(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim d As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    d = CDate(cell.Value)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        CellContentCanBeInterpretedAsADate = False
    Else
        CellContentCanBeInterpretedAsADate = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```