# Date regular expression in VB

Tags: regex, vb6

I want to validate MM/YYYY in VB6

I used (0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}

But it is not working as expected. Even it allows 5 digit year.

Comment: @Natrium It is not validating properly in VB6. It is passing 10/10/20100

Comment: Maybe even [Excel VBA date formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801598/excel-vba-date-formats)

Comment: I think you might want to try `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$`. You need to add `^` and `$` to your pattern. It will work to some extent. In other cases, use the other question to really validate the date.

Comment: @Sunny yes, I read the question. Look in the other question for the answer.