# VBA Post the value "as it is"

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am typing in my textbox in excel following: **2017-01-09** the result posted in the cell is  **42744**

What am I doing wrong here even do I am specifically saying that my cell should be formatted as a  'general' type

```
Private Sub TextBox2_LostFocus()
        Range("F3").Value = TextBox2.Value
        Range("F3").NumberFormat = "General"
        Range("F3").Select
        Application.SendKeys ("~")
        Range("F3").NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```

Comment: The general number format shows the underlying value of a date. If you want to show the actual date, then use a date-style number format.

Comment: Change the number format to "yyyy-mm-dd" to show as date

Comment: @Phylogenesis can you tell me how ?

Comment: Something like `Range("F3").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`.

Comment: that is it if you like you can post as an answer so easy thnaks for your effort

Comment: Probably useful reading for you: [Excel VBA date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801598/excel-vba-date-formats/19809413#19809413)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is -

```
Range("F3").Value = TextBox2.Text

Range("F3").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
With Range("F3") 
 .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
 .FormulaR1C1 = "2017-01-09"
End With
```